# Take photo when pattern is detected in image with Android OpenCV

Tags: android, image, opencv, image-processing, camera

Hello stackoverflow community I would like if someone can guide me a little regarding my next question, I want to make an application that takes a photo when it detects a sheet with 3 marks (black squares in the corners) similar to what a QR would have. I have read a little about opencv that I think could help me more however I am not very clear yet.

Here my example

[image: Photo to capture with patterns]

Comment: I would recommend reading about [Camera2 Api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary), thanks to it you can create your own **Image Analysis** use case in which you can implement any logic you need.

Answer (score 2):

Once you obtain your binary image, you can find contours and filter using contour approximation and contour area. If the approximated contour has a length of four then it must be a square and if it is within a lower and upper area range then we have detected a mark. We keep a counter of the mark and if there are three marks in the image, we can take the photo. Here's the visualization of the process.

We [Otsu's threshold](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#otsus-binarization) to obtain a binary image with the objects to detect in white.

[image]

From here we find contours using [`cv2.findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) and filter using contour approximation [`cv2.approxPolyDP`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp) in addition to contour area [`cv2.contourArea`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea).

Detected marks highlighted in teal

[image]

I implemented it in Python but you can adapt the same approach

Code

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and filter using contour approximation and contour area
marks = 0
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4 and area > 250 and area < 400:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (200,255,12), 2)
        marks += 1

# Sheet has 3 marks
if marks == 3:
    print('Take photo')

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```